# Get data with comma separated when running shell?

Tags: shell, centos

I want to get data with comma separated when running shell script.See sample output;

```
 value1,value2,value3
```

Is there any ideas?I'm using centos 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=',' read v1 v2 v3
```

IFS is the separator variable built in bash.